# Electron - How to make a certificate select pop up window?

Tags: electron, client-certificates

I am trying to wrap my head around Electron [select-client-certificate](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-select-client-certificate). My goal to is to have something like Chrome that pops up and the end user can select which certificate they should use to sign in.

[image: Select certificate in Chrome]

Electron by default selects the first available certificate which will not work for the site they are trying to access. Using a specific name also does not work as users are assigned slightly different certificates.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read the certificate list (which is one of the parameter of select-client-certificate and then popup a window to let user select one of the cert.

```
        browserWindow.webContents.on("select-client-certificate", (event, url, certificateList, callback) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
        // Go through the certificateList
        // certificateList is just Array<Certificate>
        // Show a popup and render the cert list, let user select one
        callback(userSelectedCert);
    });
```

Comment: I get the error "callback is not a function", even though callback parameter exist following typings (using typescript, roughly equivalent to doc).

Comment: Those are pseudo code so you will need to define your own callback function.